# HELP -- errors generated, when I, from /etc "source tmux.conf". How do I repair these errors? Which is right mode-mouse/mouse-mode

Tags: tmux, opensuse

```
root@abyss/home # source tmux.conf
 set-window-option: command not found
tmux.conf (line 2):
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on
^
from sourcing file tmux.conf
 set-option: command not found
tmux.conf (line 3):
set-option -g set-titles on
^
from sourcing file tmux.conf
 unbind: command not found
tmux.conf (line 6):
unbind C-b
^
```

Answer (score 2):

`source tmux.conf` invoked in a shell that understands `source` (e.g. in Bash) makes the shell interpret `tmux.conf`. The file contains commands for tmux, not for a shell.

You want to make tmux interpret the file. Invoke:

```
tmux source tmux.conf
```

The above will work from the inside or from the outside of tmux (assuming there is a tmux server running). Alternatively, interactively, but only from the inside of tmux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`source tmux.conf`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

<sup>(Note: this solution assumes default key bindings for the tmux prefix and `command-prompt`. If the relevant bindings in your tmux are different then you need to adjust the solution accordingly.)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

`tmux.conf` is a `tmux` configuration file, read by `tmux`. It's NOT a `bash` script or fragment. `source`ing `tmux.conf` feeds it through the current `bash`, which doesn't understand `tmux` directives. Read `man tmux`, see [tmux config mouseless](https://thevaluable.dev/tmux-config-mouseless/).

Comment: thanks...would you be able to tell how to output the execution of the tmux.conf? How can I retain the output text sent to the status bar of tmux??